# Как правильно использовать префиксы для css

Tags: html, css, gulp

Вопрос по префиксам для CSS-свойств. Если для каждого свойства добавлять префикс, код сложно прочесть. Мне интересно, как это реализуют на проде? Возможно стоит выносить префиксы в другой CSS-файл и подключать отдельно? И как можно упростить добавление префиксов, возможно у `gulp` есть такая функция?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer    .........  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer

Comment: _«возможно у галп есть такая функция»_ - gulp уже можно считать мертвым, еще с тех пор как webpack стал дружественнее в настройке (и после вебпака появилось множество других бандлеров... смысла в таскерах сейчас не больше, чем в jQuery например... сам подход "дробления" задач подготовки проекта на кучу инструментов, устарел: с комплексными и более стабильными "мультитулами" значительно удобнее работать).

Comment: Тот же свежий Vite, если помню верно, автоматически автопрефиксит все по списку целевых браузеров, т.к. уже тащит на борту настроенный PostCSS со всеми бойлерплейтами (но для серьезных больших проектов, все равно предпочтительнее надежность вебпака, т.к. вит еще молод и пока что не умеет в sourcemaps для SCSS, а это приемлемо только с малыми проектами, где стилей соотв. немного. Если же самостоятельно настраивать бортовой Rollup, то смысл в вит частично теряется).

Answer (score 1):

Правильней всего – не писать префиксы вручную вовсе. Используйте для этого [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer). Для Gulp есть плагин [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer).